# Regular PHP code inside XSLT template, is it possible?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I wonder If I can and how can I include code inside my XSLT template... I know I can use `<xsl:choose>` but that doesn't satisfy my needs, I want to add functions, variables etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  

<xsl:template match="BackgroundReportPackage">

<!--- here i would like to add code like ---->

if ($dateofcharge < 7) {
return '

<xsl:for-each select="Charge">
            <table class="special2" cellpadding="0">
                <tr class="tr-border-bottom">
                    <td class="front-td-text" valign="top">Charge ID: </td>
                    <td class="minimalec">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ChargeId"/>           
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="tr-border-bottom">
                    <td class="front-td-text" valign="top">Charge Type Classification: </td>
                    <td class="minimalec">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ChargeTypeClassification"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>                   

            </table>

';          
} else {
 do nothing
 }

 <!--- keep in mind that this code i've added is just for presentational purposes TO show you, how i want to use php code --->

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: You can certainly have a PHP script generate xslt as output. But I don't think you can have an xslt template call on PHP to evaluate portions of the template.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php and see also http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php - you can access streams from within XML/XSLT as well, like `myvar://variablename` (if you have build one that does this).

Comment: You did not accept an answer yet. Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer and why the given answers do not satisfy you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real reason why you would write a template like that when XSLT can do if blocks. What you can look into is

- [`XSLTProcessor::setParameter` — Set value for a parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php)

to change template values and

- [`XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions` — Enables the ability to use PHP functions as XSLT functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php)

to use PHP functions inside the template. This will probably make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't like that.
You can include code from external namespaces, which is how you would write extension functions but I suspect you wouldn't be able to do them in PHP, they are normally in pre compiled languages as you have to load libraries to do it.

What is it you need to achieve. there is not that much that you can't achieve with XSL if you put your mind to it, certainly you wouldn't have a problem with something trivial like your example